# Cannot open file, path = 'file:///path' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi I am trying reduce image size picked from gallery using image library
while trying that I am facing error like this

```
E/flutter (13796): [ERROR:lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)]    Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (13796): FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20171016-WA0020.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter (13796): #0      _File.throwIfError (file_impl.dart:618)
E/flutter (13796): #1      _File.openSync (file_impl.dart:473)
E/flutter (13796): #2      _File.readAsBytesSync (file_impl.dart:533)
E/flutter (13796): #3      _AddNewUserState.qqq (/data/data/com.prayuta.chitfunds/cache/chitfundsUNFPRG/chitfunds/lib/users.dart:420:97)
E/flutter (13796): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13796): #4      _AddNewUserState.build.<anonymous closure> (/data/data/com.prayuta.chitfunds/cache/chitfundsUNFPRG/chitfunds/lib/users.dart:686:19)
E/flutter (13796): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter (13796): #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:149:9)
E/flutter (13796): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:119:7)
E/flutter (13796): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (13796): #9          BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:147:20)
E/flutter (13796): #10     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
E/flutter (13796): #11     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (13796): #12     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
E/flutter (13796): #13     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
E/flutter (13796): #14     _invoke1 (file:///b/build/slave/Linux_Engine/build/src/flutter/lib/ui/hooks.dart:100)
   E/flutter (13796): #15     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (file:///b/build/slave/Linux_Engine/build/src/flutter/lib/ui/hooks.dart:58)
```

can any one help and my code look like this

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as convertinglib;
File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage();
convertinglib.Image image = convertinglib.decodeImage(new Io.File(imageFile.uri.toString()).readAsBytesSync());
convertinglib.Image thumbnail = convertinglib.copyResize(image, 120);
```

Comment: What does package:image/image.dart look like? The image picker seems to be working fine.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of a working class, which produces the error?

Comment: imageuploader() async {
    File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage();
    convertinglib.Image image = convertinglib.decodeImage(new Io.File(imageFile.uri.toString()).readAsBytesSync());
    convertinglib.Image thumbnail = convertinglib.copyResize(image, 120);
    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
    var datestamp = new DateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
    String currentdate = datestamp.format(now);
    setState(() {
      progressBarStatus = true;
    });

Comment: But what is ```convertinglib``` is it something you wrote yourself?

Comment: convertinglib is just alias name for the library

Comment: showing error as "The Name 'image' is defined in libraries image.dart and image.dart "while importing import 'package:image/image.dart'; (or) import 'package:dart_image/dart_image.dart'; is to eliminate this I had created alias name

Comment: have you identified, where the error comes from? I can read and display images from the image picker perfectly. converting it with convertingLib also works with no error. Maybe you are trying to write the file back to the filesystem somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the issue is passing the Image URI as a String.
There is a `fromUri` constructor where you can pass the file URI.

Try using

```
    new Io.File.fromUri(imageFile.uri)
```

instead of

```
    new Io.File(imageFile.uri.toString())
```

Comment: the problem is, that the image_picker hides the real url from the app. See my answer for more information.

Comment: but I want return type as file to upload firebase storage

Comment: indeed. when you want to load `imageUrlString` generated by `image_picker` into `File` then you should use  `File.fromUri(Uri.parse(imageUrlString))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in reading the file with the image picker or with the conversion to a smaller size but with the writing of the file to the file system. I take it, you took the example code of the [dart image package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image)
which writes the file to the file system after resizing it. This is in this form not possible on smartphones.

The code you posted didn't actually cause the error but this line did:

```
new Io.File(imageFile.uri.toString())
   ..writeAsBytesSync(convertingLib.encodePng(thumbnail))
```

The problem with this is that the imagePicker hides the real uri of the image. It gives you a path that looks something like this: `.../tmp/image_picker_1547A964-791E-426F-A682-33D3AFA995BA-18295-0003861F9255294A.jpg` which can't be used to save your new thumbnail.

You can either try to avoid saving the file in the first place or save it to a location that actually exists (you could use for example the [path_provider plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) for that purpose).

Comment: then how to fix it, or can u say is there any other way

Comment: but I want return as file how to get it