# when upload image then Catch error FileSystemException in dart

Tags: flutter

```
V/FA      (30346): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/tempBitmap(30346): android.graphics.Bitmap@ea149a
V/aashari-tag(30346): getEdgePoints
V/aashari-tag(30346): getContourEdgePoints
V/aashari-tag(30346): orderedValidEdgePoints
I/flutter (30346): add contacts result is /data/user/0/com.cloveritservices.bizcardscanner/files/Image1657388395.jpeg
I/flutter (30346): Image captured URI :  /data/user/0/com.cloveritservices.bizcardscanner/files/Image1657388395.jpeg
D/FA      (30346): Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivities, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-8859723700592013815, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8859723700592013818}]
I/flutter (30346): Catch error FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '/data/user/0/com.cloveritservices.bizcardscanner/files/Image1657388395.jpeg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
V/FA      (30346): Connecting to remote service
V/FA      (30346): Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA      (30346): Activity resumed, time: 11380335
D/FA      (30346): Connected to remote service
V/FA      (30346): Processing queued up service tasks: 2
```

Comment: are you sure that are you saving the image in the internal storage in:
/data/user/0/com.cloveritservices.bizcardscanner/files/Image1657388395.jpeg

Comment: check this one please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782521/cannot-open-file-path-file-path-os-error-no-such-file-or-directory-er